# Custom cursor image just for one div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a custom cursor for a specific div but the code makes the cursor custom for whole page, I couldn't figure it out, can you help me?

I just want the custom cursor just in the "container" div which is purple colored.

Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/k6nb0hss/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){console.log($("container").length)
$("div").css('cursor','url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/beach/128/shark-icon.png),auto');
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k6nb0hss/1/ this?

Comment: Hi, friend you need configure the cursor in particular div right??

Comment: @Learner thanks a lot, that's my lack of knowledge about jquery :)

Comment: @ErenAlkan always accept an answer so it will helpfull to others :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("div#container")
```

instead of

```
$("div")
```

Your selector, `$("div")` applies the css to every single div element on page. With `$("div#container")` or `$("#container")` you select the desired element specifying the id of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$('div')` it will apply for every div element. Instead of this you have to use ID selector or class selector. Do this:

```
$("#container").css('cursor','url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/beach/128/shark-icon.png),auto');
```

Updated question with id `#` use this with class use `.`. Read in brief [**Jquery Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2eu499h/)

---

You can also do this without Jquery with simple css:

```
#container {
    width:960px;
    height:100vh;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#7E33DB;
    cursor: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/beach/128/shark-icon.png),auto  /*added */
}
```

[**CSS DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgr4wkf0/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply custom cursor to a specific div then, user specific div id/class in js where you're changing the cursor.